# add existing plot into axes/ subplot framework

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have `df`s such as the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Country': ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
  'Answer declined': [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000667, 0.000833, 0.000833, 0.000000],
  "Don't know": [0.003333, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.001333, 0.001667, 0.000000, 0.000000],
  "No": [0.769167, 0.843333, 0.762000, 0.666000, 0.721667, 0.721667, 0.775833],
  "Yes": [0.227500, 0.156667, 0.238000, 0.332000, 0.275833, 0.277500, 0.224167]}, )
df.set_index("Country", inplace = True)
```

As I have multiple such `df`s from which I want to create plots from, I have defined the below function:

```
def bar_plot(plot_df):
    N = len(plot_df) # number of groups
    ind = np.arange(N) # x locations for the groups
    width = 0.35 # width of bars

    p_s = []
    p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,0], width))
    for i in range(1,len(plot_df.columns)):
        p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,i], width,
                           bottom=np.sum(plot_df.iloc[:,:i], axis=1)))

    plt.ylabel('[%]')
    plt.title('Responses by country')

    x_ticks_names = tuple([item for item in plot_df.index])

    plt.xticks(ind, x_ticks_names)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)) # ticks from, to, steps
    #if num_y_cats % 3 == 0: ncol = num_y_cats / 3
    #else: ncol = num_y_cats % 3
    ncol = 3
    plt.legend(p_s, plot_df.columns,
               bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, -0.25), # to the left; to the top
               loc = 'lower center',
               ncol = ncol,
               borderaxespad = 0)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

calling the function (`bar_plot(df)`) gives the desired plot. However, I want to manipulate/ fine tune the plots and therefore want to **embed the plot into `mpl` `figure`s and `axe`s** but have failed to do so, since I can't figure out how to make it work with the lines `p_s = []` and `p_s.append(...)`.

Could someone help me out where the `fig = plt.figure()`, `fig.add_axes()`, and `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)` would go?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the last two lines from your function. This lines must be called after defining all the figures and subplots.

```
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

For example, after deleting those lines from the function, you can call the function using different subplots:

```
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
bar_plot(df1)
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
bar_plot(df2)
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
bar_plot(df3)
```

And finally:

```
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I suppose this could work.

Comment: Both subplot, add_sunplot, and figure, can be used outside the function call.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer does address the issue for the shown plot in the console. For the file saved with `plt.savefig(filename.png)`, however, the command `bbox_inches='tight'` does the trick conveniently:

```
plt.savefig(filename.png, bbox_inches='tight')
```